# save pointer address from another function

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function which receives a pointer to a char array. The function increments the pointer so that it traverses n length through the array. In the end the function returns an int which signifies certain state. The problem is I have other functions who also receive a pointer to the same char array and they need to start traversing it exactly where another function left off. So I need to somehow save the address of the pointer. I can't return the pointer because the function returns int. I'm wondering if I can still somehow pull this off or I need to use structs in order to save several data types (int and pointer address).

Here's an example of such a function:

```
int func(char *p) {
    while(*p != 's')
       p++;
    return (*p == 's') ? 1 : -1
}
```

Comment: You have different options here. Is the function signature fixed? Otherwise you could pass a second argument to each function which contains the last position within the array, i.e. another pointer which will be updated by each function.

Comment: the signature is fixed but were it not how would I return multiple arguments?

Comment: The function returns 1 or never returns (but probably runs into undefined behaviour sooner or later). The code as shown does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the pointer:

```
// The ** means a pointer to a pointer, you can now edit the pointer.
int func(char **p) {
    // Mauybe check for the end of the string here as well.
    while(*(*p) != 's') {
       // We dereference our pointer and edit it here.
       (*p)++;
    }
    return (*(*p) == 's') ? 1 : -1
}
```

At the end of this function your `p` will point at the position where the loop stopped. You would call it like this:

```
char *p = someString;
int myInt = func(&p);
```

**If the function signature is fixed** then this is not possible without the use of a global, or the same loop in your second function to "re-find" this position.

Comment: when you say fixed signature do you mean that it is not a function with variable arguments length?

Comment: @Yos I mean, if you cannot change the function from `int func(char *p)` to anything else.

Comment: I didn't still don't understand what's fixed signature. do you mean if I'm using overloading?

Comment: @Yos I literally  mean, if someone has told you you cannot change the prototype of this function.

Comment: @Yos Ok, then ignore the comment.

Comment: Using char**p as an argument is dangerous if the caller passes a pointer that was allocated using malloc or calloc, since you will lose the reference to the original pointer and thus can never free it.

Comment: @FredK Plenty of things in c are dangerous, but this sort of thing is done a lot. A good comment on the API would be (and is almost always) required.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to use double pointers. Either by changing the argument to be a char**, in which case the function would look a lot uglier, or by adding a new "out" argument of type char**, which is the address of the pointer where the new value of the pointer will be stored - sort of simulating another return value.

Here's the first option:

```
int func(char **p) {
    while (**p != 's')
        ++*p;
    return **p == 's' ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a struct containing the state and the pointer or you can make a global pointer

Comment: global is not an option unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

how about pointer to a pointer:

```
int func(char **p) {
    while(**p != 's')
       (*p)++;
    return (**p == 's') ? 1 : -1;
}
```

You would call it using:

```
func(&pointer);
```

Comment: I think you're actually incrementing p (not *p), which won't change the original pointer.